# How to set different static IPs to each docker containers with in the same host?

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, docker, containers, static-ip-address

I am trying to assign static IPs for each docker containers.but docker assigns dynamic IPs for each containers all the time.Is there any location to configure files to achieve this or any command to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Docker doesn't offer a way of doing it directly. You can create a bridge with the range you wish, and then tell Docker daemon to use that bridge with  `-b BRIDGE` or `--bridge=BRIDGE` options. Check [the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#building-your-own-bridge) and [this post from jpetazzo](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2013/10/16/configure-docker-bridge-network/) to check the details.